# Ngx-bootstrap: Modal inside Modal container position is not working for datepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Datepicker container opening in random place when we place the [Ngx-Bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) modal inside another modal.
Note: Inner dailog has datepicker element.

For reference please check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-open-modal-kekpkn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update**:  Closing the previous modal will solve the issue but we need to maintain the state without closing the previous modal.
And need to append the datepicker container to specific element

Comment: Date picker calendar opens in the first modal instead of the second modal. To fix this issue you need to close first modal and then open the second modal. As suggested by @Đỗ văn Thắng

Comment: @SantoshShelke We need to maintain the previous modal state also

Answer (score 1):

You can close modal1 before opening modal2 in your ts file. For example:

```
openModal2(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef.hide();
    this.modalRef2 = this.modalService.show(template, {
      animated: true,
      backdrop: "static"
    });
  }
```

Comment: Here needed previous modal state also.
I mean when user close the top modal we should show the first modal

Comment: You can using one modal and toggle display

Answer (score 0):

`container` only supports "body", remove `[container]="'.test'"` from your code. It should work.

Comment: @Santhosh Please check this doc.
NGX-BS team says it string as valid selector.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#bs-datepicker-component

Comment: I need to append the datepicker container to specific element

Comment: check out official page of bootstrap. They mentioned only supports "body".
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbInputDatepicker

Comment: It is worked for me when removed .class selector which is wrong.

Comment: It is ng-bootstrap doc. am working with ngx-bootstrap